# How to read outlook emails and Extract information using C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on a small C# console Utility. As https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx is disabled by Microsoft So I am not able to authenticate the Microsoft account getting 401 unauthorized error.

I am trying to find other ways to implement the logic.

So, what are the other options/ways to authenticate Microsoft account and read emails (Unibody, from, ConversaionId, InternetMessageId, DateTimeReceived, subject, body) from Outlook inbox with filters. Like: passing the date range and count of emails.

example: if I want to read last 24 hrs. received emails how can I extract all information like **Unibody, from, ConversaionId, InternetMessageId, DateTimeReceived, subject, body** from each email.

Please help.

Comment: Using the Graph API?

Comment: Or are you just stumbling over that basic auth is obsolete (plain user&password authentication) and you should use OAuth?